# Ajax GET Requests With wildcards

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to send an Ajax request in HTML to fetch an object in a JSON file. here is my code in HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>JSON Server Test</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var findData = (id) => {
                $('.submit-button').on('click', (e) => {
                    e.preventDefault();

                    console.log('submit button pressed');

                    var data = {};
                    data.title = "title";
                    data.message = "message";

                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'GET',
                        data: JSON.stringify(data),
                        contentType: 'application/json',
                        url: 'localhost:3000/people?id=' + id,
                        success: (data) => {
                            console.log('success');
                            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                        }
                    });
                });
            };
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var findData = (id) => {
                $('.submit-button').on('click', (e) => {
                    e.preventDefault();

                    console.log('submit button pressed');

                    var data = {};
                    data.title = "title";
                    data.message = "message";

                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'GET',
                        data: JSON.stringify(data),
                        contentType: 'application/json',
                        url: 'localhost:3000/people?id=' + id,
                        success: (data) => {
                            console.log('success');
                            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                            document.getElementById('final-data').innerHTML 
= JSON.stringify(data);
                        }
                    });
                });
            };
            </script>
        <input id="input" type="number">
        <button class="submit-button" 
        onclick="findData(getElementById('input').value)">Find 
        Person</button>
        <p id="final-data"></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is my NodeJS code:

```
const express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/" + "index.html");
});

app.listen(4000, () => {
    console.log('Listening on port 4000');
});
```

The actual server itself is running on a localhost on port 3000 using a json-server on a cmd.

```
json-server --watch db.json
```

The problem is when I actually press the "Submit" button in the frontend, nothing gives back a response. No console logging, no actual change in the paragraph element in the HTML, nothing.

EDIT: I did manage to do it, it works, but one more thing: I am getting an array with the data, but I want to break it so I get every property alone. How do I do that?

Comment: I think your problem is that the server is listening on port 4000 and you are trying to reach it on port 300

Comment: You're using the `onclick` attribute AND a jQuery event handler. Pick one (I'd suggest the latter).

Comment: Okay, but can you give me the specific syntax that I need to use?

Comment: Please Check the console. You may get message something like `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`

Comment: Nope. I think you didn't really understand my issue. I said that when I send Ajax GET requests to my JSON Server, I'm getting an array, but how do I chop it up to the different properties and then put all the properties nicely in a paragraph or in a list?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: what is the ata return type of your server, is it json ?

Comment: How do I set the return type? The return type is an array.

Comment: array in what format? json/xml? can you show us an example of response?